# Return an array of objects from 'pages' in which content matches 'pattern'?

Tags: javascript

```
var pages = ["/garethnunns.com/simply a brilliant site, that has a bunch of beautiful content / stuff ", " - http: //bbc.co.uk-Some news ", " | www.google.com | What an OG, wow "]

function urls(pages, pattern) {
  //returns an array of urls from pages where 
  //content matches pattern 

  for (var i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) {
    var string = pages[i].split(pages[i].charAt(0));
    if (match(pages[i], pattern)) {
      return string[1]
    }
    return ''
  }
}
```

The code works for the most part, but I cannot seem to get it to return multiple objects from an array. It will only ever return the 1st part of the array, or return an empty string.

When `urls(pages,"w")` was run it should have returned `["http://bbc.co.uk","www.google.com"]`, instead it returned an empty string.

Comment: a return in a function returns from the function

Comment: Okay, how would I go about changing that to make it return multiple parts of the array in which the content matches pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your logic:

1. Enter the loop
2. Look at the first item
3. If there is a match: return the first item (this exits the function, and the loop)
4. If there isn't  a match: return an empty string (this exits the function, and the loop).

You need to change your approach.

You said you want to return an array. So you need to:

- Have an array to return
- Put your `return` statement before that array instead of before a string

Start by creating that array before the loop.

Then, inside the loop, your logic shouldn't return. It should add items to the array.

Finally, once you have looped over all the data, return the new array you just created and populated.

Comment: Thank you. I'll give it a try. :)